# JSONObject - recreate or remove key (high performance demand)

Tags: java, json, performance, garbage-collection

I'm implementating method which will be run periodically (instant work in the background). My question is that if I want to increase the performance of the app, which of the following two code snippets should I use?

```
            for (EtInstance evt : activeSystemEvents) {

               JSONObject EventJSON = new JSONObject();

               EventJSON.put("alarmLevel", evt.getAlarm());
               EventJSON.put("activeTimeStamp", evt.getTimestamp());
               EventJSON.put("id", evt.getId());
               activeEventsJSON.put(EventJSON);
        }
```

or maybe 2nd.:

```
            for (EtInstance evt : activeSystemEvents) {

                  JSONObject EventJSON = new JSONObject();
                  EventJSON.put("alarmLevel", evt.getAlarm());
                  EventJSON.put("activeTimeStamp", evt.getTimestamp());
                  EventJSON.put("id", evt.getId());

                  activeEventsJSON.put(EventJSON);      
                  EventJSON.remove("alarmLevel");
                  EventJSON.remove("activeTimeStamp");
                  EventJSON.remove("id");
        }
```

Comment: You're increasing the instructions to be processed by the JVM in the second snippet. As per the answer by Daniel Diment, the garbage collection takes care of the objects to be deleted.

Comment: alternative 2 will not work unless activeEventsJSON.put() handles events synchronously  or is a copy-on-call method. You are removing data from the instance you just put into the event queue, ie you are modifying the data in the queue so this will not work. But, alternative 1 will not only work, it will be faster.

Comment: Thank You for prompt response!

Answer (score 0):

Since java does memory management for you, you don't have to worry about deleting objects, nor to remove parts of the object because as soon as java realizes that you're not going to use that variable anymore is going to delete it, so I suggest you use the first snippet.